# Using all physical or logical cores for multiprocessing?

Tags: multithreading, fortran

I think this question isn't new, but I couldn't find a clear answer for this: I have a Fortran-code and a Intel core i7 with 6 physical and 12 logical cores. At this moment my code is running on the 6 physical cores, i.e. on each core is running the same code. I saw at the inter power gadget that the utilization is ca. 50%, therefore I want to know if I get my results (nearly) twice as fast if I run the code on the 12 logical cores. I have also heard that I get in certain circumstances my results slower if I use the logical cores for running the code, so I'm not sure about what to do.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you try it? Seriously - that's the only way to know one way or the other